# How to match a pattern but not when a specific tag is present

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match: --This is a text and it <b>can contain other </b> tags--

I will wrap matched pattern with `<u></u>`
But i'm trying to avoid `<br>` tag only. I.e it shouldn't match if the string has <br> in between --

```
text.replace(/(?:--)(?:(?!--|\s))((?!<br>).*?)(?:--)/g,'<u>$1</u>')
```

Unfortunately, my regex matches

--This is a text, <b>can contain other</b>tags but don't match if <br> is present--

I don't expect it to match since <br> is present.

Comment: You can also use a function as replacer, eg: [`text.replace(/--(.*?)--/g, (m,m1) => m.match(/<br/) ? m : '<u>' + m1 +'</u>');`](https://tio.run/##ZY3BDsIgEETv/Yq9QW0X0ptRSr8FEFsNSEOxGn8eaaKnXmYz8zYzd7WqxcTbnHA95uxsgmTfCXogiNcQQGipVRRcS9Dqg1g0wh9FueeTdS6Uj1eI7rLD5FxVv4HtsGhnp4ylHJGyw1Aj8rEF6lvf1dBL8MyrZCbKyxivYQAPJyDiKQk04DtoiODF1KXWhMcSnGUujHTrLlnOXw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `(?!<br>).` as a group, then quantify this group, instead of quantifying `.` only. Aslo, `?` is redundant after `*` because `?` means 0 or 1 while `*` means 0 or more, which already cover 1.

```
(?:--)(?:(?!--|\s))((?:(?!<br>).)*)(?:--)
```

Bonus: You don't need capture group if you use positive look ahead and positive look behind for `--`, if your environment support it. This match itself will exclude the `--`.

```
(?<=--)(?:(?!--|\s))(?:(?!<br>).)*(?=--)
```

Comment: It seems my environment doesnt support the bonus. The first works perfect. Thanks

Comment: Just to mention, it will match eg. whole string: [`--foo-- bar --baz--`](https://regex101.com/r/PacGrI/1)

Comment: @bobble you are right, i solved it with:  (?:--)(?:(?!\s))((?:(?!<br>|--).)*)(?:--)

Answer (score 1):

First check if string does not contain `<br>` and then continue regex:

```js
if (!/--.*?<br>.*?--/.test(text)) {
    text.replace(/(?:--)(?:(?!--|\s))((?!<br>).*?)(?:--)/g,'<u>$1</u>')  
}
```